# Efficient Map for small ranges of integers

Tags: java, performance, dictionary, hashmap

So I have a program that uses a number of HashMaps that store a low number of integer keys, between 0 and 50, whose keys represent a unique ordinal less than 100.

These maps are accessed very often and I have done profiling to identify that it will help to have more a more efficient datastructure.  Ideally I would use something akin to EnumMap, as these integers are small and unique.

Restrictions: I'm trying to avoid using an array as many of these maps only have a handful of the possible keys. I'm also trying to avoid 3rd party libraries.  Large libraries are definitely out, though small libraries, or just 1 or 2 classes might be alright.

Does anyone know of a good fast Map for this situation?

Comment: I can't see anything being faster than a 50-element array.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using an array if possible. It just seems like a waste to allocate all the space when only a fraction is needed. But if there truly is nothing else..

Comment: Time and space are almost _always_ tradeoffs. A 50 element array is **absolutely tiny.** Get over it. You're just not going to get any faster than single-opcode array indexing, unless you change your entire approach.

Comment: I know there are always tradeoffs, in this case I'm trying to have a small memory footprint and the time savings. They have exactly this for enums in EnumMap and since my case is so similar I was hoping for something easy like this as well

Comment: For what it's worth, an EnumMap internally just has an array whose size is the number of elements in the enum.

Comment: Sure, but you seem to dislike the idea of a 50-element array. You imply that you'd like something as good as EnumMap, but for ints instead of enums; I'm just pointing out that this is a false dichotomy, since an EnumMap for an enum of 50 elements would just be a 50-element array.

Comment: Which kind of sounds like the ideal situation, speed near straight array access, but less memory used.  I mean, if using arrays were always the answer for this question, why even have the EnumMap be a default java class.  I can't think of any enums that have more than 50 elements.

Comment: What I'm saying is that I often have less than this, sometimes 1-5 elements.  Rarely am I getting up to 30 or 50 elements.

Comment: To say "I want something fast but more space efficient than a 50-element array, akin to what EnumMap would give me" is basically to say "I want something different than a 50-element array, akin to a 50-element array." That's all I'm saying. :) I don't think it's fair to say "but most EnumMaps have a smaller domain so they take less space," because it's exactly the (typically) smaller domain that allows them to (typically) take less space, and that doesn't apply to your situation. It's not that EnumMap is doing some magic to solve the time-vs-space tradeoff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array should be reasonably efficient, given your Keys are <= 100;  the size of the array will be 400 bytes. I don't know that the Entries of a Map structure, wouldn't be reasonably close to this size.

Does it matter if your maps (as arrays) total say 4MB, or 40MB, or whatever?  You can set the JVM heap large.

Alternative 2):

- Write your own Hash-based map class (not implementing collections.Map).  Relatively simple using a 'linear probe' in an array of cells -- the other technique is a linked-list, which (again) will be as large as the 'direct array' option.

Comment: Maybe its just the c programmer in me being paranoid, it just seems to be a waste to allocate 100 spaces when only 10 might be needed. Especially since I have a lot of these maps, which multiplies that problem.  It's still probably a small amount of memory... I'll have to think about my own Map class.  What is the linear probe approach? I dont know that one

Comment: Map has to have more cells than elements, since hashcodes & the cells they map to are not guaranteed unique. (You're really fighting against using an array here, aren't you?) Different elements with same 'intended' cell are thus stored in the next empty cell. Lookup requires a linear scan along the hashmap from the indicated cell, scanning all non-empty cells (potential collisions) until the target is found or an empty cell is reached. HashMap size thus must always be greater than the # elements held, by a 'load factor'.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probing

Comment: If you want performance, _my comment above_ should indicate that an array will be an order of magnitude faster & simpler than even your own custom map implementation.

Answer (score 3):

[GNU Trove has primitive maps](http://trove.starlight-systems.com) that will do what you want.  But if you are not trying to eke out every byte of memory, I'd second Thomas's suggestion to just use an array.

Comment: I always forget about Trove. +1

Comment: I'm liking this.  Haven't heard of Trove before and it's looking good.  It's a pretty big library though so I'll have to see if I can just isolate the map I'll need from it.

Comment: The point is, your memory usage for even a (well optimized) primitive hash-map will be almost as much as a direct array. Calculate it! And execution cost will be around 5-10x slower. _Frankly, at this point you're pursuing non-productive efforts._

Comment: @ThomasW: It could be worthwhile, if you say have a valid range of 100 keys, have *many many* separate maps, and many of them only have 0-10 entries in them.  But I agree with you that the array is the better choice unless there really is a convincing reason to use a sparse `Map`.